# offsetHeight Getting Incorrect Height of div Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center a div on my screen by making its position absolute, setting its top value to 50%, and then subtracting the top margin by half of the div's height. I am using offsetHeight, but it seems that the height returned by the offsetHeight property is less than the actual height of the div element. (See screenshot below)

Is there a fix for this? Is there an alternative that I can do instead of this?

Thanks in advance.

The height returned by offsetHeight is 69 px instead of the actual height, which is 328.375px.

```js
// Custom title
let customTitle = document.getElementById("title");
chrome.storage.sync.get("title", (result) => {
  customTitle.textContent = result.title;
});

// Centering container
let container = document.getElementById("container");
container.style.marginTop = -container.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
window.onresize = container.style.marginTop = -container.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
```

```css
pre {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 96px;
  margin-block-start: 0.2em;
  margin-block-end: 0.2em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 2.7px white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgba(168, 166, 166, 0);
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="blocked.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <pre id="title"></pre>
    <button id="unblockButton">
                Unblock
            </button>
  </div>
  <script src="blocked.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using styling like this, you don't need to use javascript at all.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* This moves container upword by its half height */
    left: 10%;
}
```